# Is the "edge with the highest weight" in the minimum spanning tree held the smallest weight?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, discrete-optimization

This question seems confusing, take the following graph as an example:

[image]

In this graph, the **minimum spanning tree** holds edge weights as $4,5,6$, the maximum value of them is $6$.

There are other spanning trees in this graph as well. For example, edges with weight $5,6,9$, the maximum value of them if $9$, $9>6$.

In fact, for every spanning tree in this graph, **the highest weight edge** is higher than 6. The minimum value is held by **minimum spanning tree**.

Is this true for **all graphs**? Or there is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m(T)$ denote the maximum weight of an edge in $T$. Your statement is not true in general, for trivial reasons, for instance all weights being the same. However, what is true is that a minimum spanning tree (MST) will minimize $m(T)$ among all spanning trees. The difference between these two statements is that it is not necessarily a strict inequality.

Let us prove that if $T$ is an MST, then $T$ minimizes $m(T)$ among all spanning trees. Suppose not. That is, there exists a spanning tree $T'$ such that $m(T)>m(T')$. Let $e\in T$ be an edge of weight $m(T)$. Now, the graph $T'\cup \{e\}$ contains a cycle $C_e$ (known as the fundamental cycle of $e$ with respect to $T'$). Observe that since $e$ is the only edge of $C_e$ in $T$, all other edges in $C_e$ are in $T'$, and thus have smaller weight. Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be the two components of $T\backslash \{e\}$. Then there exists $f\in C_e$ distinct from $e$ joining $T_1$ and $T_2$, since $T'$ is a spanning tree. But then $T_1\cup T_2\cup\{f\}$ is a spanning tree of lower weight than $T$, a contradiction.